# how to add number from 1 t0 20000 in python programming

Tags: python

If we add number  from 1 to 6 we have to add it again and again. if we have to add number from 1 to 20000 it is difficult to write code one by one how to write program such a way that it can print in one few line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for the sum of an arithmetic series to quickly calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to 20000. The formula for the sum of the first n natural numbers is given by:

[image]

In your case,

```
n = 20000
sum_of_numbers = (n * (n + 1)) // 2
print(f"The sum of numbers from 1 to {n} is: {sum_of_numbers}")
```